# Phase shift of two sine curves

Tags: fourier-analysis, graphing-functions, matlab

How do I determine phase shift of two sine curves (discrete time sampled sine curves) in Matlab. Currently, I have the FFT of these two sine curves, the phase shift is just the delay in time, which coresponds to the change of the phase angle. My question is, is it better to compare the phase shift in time domain, or do the comparison in the frequency domain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A general method is to calculate the [instantaneous phase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instantaneous_phase) for each of your discrete samples. The [Hilbert transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform), which can be represented [in terms of the Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Relationship_with_the_Fourier_transform) and it's inverse, can be used for this.

In Matlab, using the [`hilbert`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/hilbert.html), [`angle`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/angle.html), and [`unwrap`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html) functions:

```
dt = 1e-2;
t = 0:dt:20;
y1 = sin(t); h1 = hilbert(y1);
y2 = sin(t+1); h2 = hilbert(y2);
p1 = angle(h1); p2 = angle(h2); % Instantaneous phase (wrapped)
p = unwrap(p2)-unwrap(p1);      % Instantaneous phase difference

figure;
subplot(211);
plot(t,p1,'r',t,p2,'b');
subplot(212);
plot(t,p,'k');
```

The result is a figure something like this:

[image: Matlab plot]

Note, that, like the Fourier transform, this won't be accurate at the edges of your signals.  Trimming your input signals to a whole number of periods will reduce [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) effects. Type `edit hilbert` in your command window too see the code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there any other (or even better way) to calculate the difference in phase shift ?

Comment: @kuku: The Hilbert transform is a general and robust method that will work across a wide variety of unknown and/or noisy inputs (see my added note about mitigating aliasing). If you know what your input signals are, what dynamics they follow, and if they are well-behaved, you can certainly implement other schemes. For example, if your signals are clean, the frequency content is minimal and known, you may be able to estimate phase difference by looking for and aligning key points (e.g., minima, maxima, zero crossings).

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27546385/2278029) at StackOverflow.com/Matlab for a nice overview of different methods.